# How can I expose a directive's function in Angular without using @ViewChild

Tags: angular

I am crafting a directive and aiming to make a function within the directive accessible. Here's my proposed implementation. However, I'm pondering over how to expose the `trigger` function within the directive and utilize it within the template without resorting to `@ViewChild` or similar approaches.

```js
@Directive({ ... })
export class FooDirective() {
  trigger() { ... }
}

@Component({
  ...,
  imports: [FooDirective],
  template: `
     <div foo #trigger="..."></div>
     <button (click)="trigger()">Click on trigger<button>
   `
})
export class FooComponent {

}
```

In this rendition, I'm contemplating how to make the `trigger` function inside the `FooDirective` available via the `#trigger` variable within the template and leverage it appropriately.

If it possible to expose only the `trigger` function and not the instance itself, it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to utilize an `exportAs` metadata property of a `@Directive`. According to [the official documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive):

> `exportAs` defines the name that can be used in the template to assign this directive to a variable.

For more details, [see this article](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26).

Having a `@Directive` decorator involved looks like this:

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[foo]',
   exportAs: 'foo',
})
export class FooDirective {
  trigger() {
    alert('FooDirective has been triggered!');
  }
}
```

The `@Directive` instance will be assignable to a template variable via the `exportAs` value like this:

```html
<div foo #f="foo"></div>
<button type="button" (click)="f.trigger()">Trigger Foo!</button>
```

Where:

1. `<div foo ...></div>` - `foo` is the directive selector (to attach the directive to an element)
2. `<div ... #f="foo"></div>` - `#f` is a variable declaration of the directive instance imported to the template through the `foo` export name.
3. `<button ... (click)="f.trigger()">...</button>` - this button is just triggering the directive instance method through the imported variable.

Try this solution out:

```
import { Component, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Directive({
  selector: '[foo]',
  exportAs: 'foo',
  standalone: true,
})
export class FooDirective {
  trigger() {
    alert('FooDirective has been triggered!');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <div foo #f="foo"></div>
    <button type="button" (click)="f.trigger()">Trigger Foo!</button>
  `,
  imports: [FooDirective],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz@demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ujwgxm)

Comment: @JeremyCaney I've just enhanced the answer. Btw, why I got -1 vote? Is that you who gave it it the answer?

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you, no, but answers that exclusively include code with no explanation are generally frowned upon as they're not very helpful—and especially when it's a large block of code—so it makes sense that someone would have downvoted your original answer based on that. (Downvotes mean "This answer was not useful".) That said, your edits are a big improvement, and reflect the standard we're looking for on Stack Overflow. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you @JeremyCaney for this explanation. I am still quite noobe as an active user around here. So far I used to be just a consumer :)

Comment: And big thanks for correcting my answer @JeremyCaney! This shows me what's the best shape of any answer expected in here :)